# How to make an open box on top and bottom as a container with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I read a few comments and added an image, because I was not clear, sorry and thanks for your help!

I wanted to make a website with a rectangular border containing all the information, but this container should have the border opened on top and on the bottom. I have an image as a background, so I cannot make a simple div to hide some parts of the container. Of course this container should be responsive.
I thought it would be easy but I'm working all around this problem and cannot make it work.
Thanks in advance!

I want to make this: https://ibb.co/dmwP8PM

Please make changes on this test:

https://codepen.io/soporo123/pen/WNNxLmX

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background: url(https://www.gohawaii.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_gallery_bg_xl/public/hero-unit-images/11500_mauibeaches.jpg?itok=I2TvGlCa) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container{
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3em;
        margin: 3%;
        border: 5px solid #FFF;
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
    }
    .logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .logo2{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
        <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2">LOGO 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you're saying, do you want to add borders only on the Right and Left of your container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a gradient to draw partially the top and bottom borders to give room to the logos:

```
background:
    linear-gradient(to left, white 40%, transparent 40%, transparent 60%, white 60%) top no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to left, white 40%, transparent 40%, transparent 60%, white 60%) bottom no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 5px;
```

your pen forked : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxxOMwK

Comment: GREAT! that's what I was looking for! Amazing, thanks!!!!!!!!!!! Just by chance, is there a way to make the whole for the "LOGO 2" smaller? (not so wide). Thanks in advance! Just take a look: https://ibb.co/dmwP8PM

Comment: Yes, you can update  the start  stop values for the bottom gradient .40/60% is actually used. It could be 45/55% to make the hole smaller.

Answer (score 1):

`border-left` and `border-right` should get you there.

```css
body{
        background: url(https://www.gohawaii.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_gallery_bg_xl/public/hero-unit-images/11500_mauibeaches.jpg?itok=I2TvGlCa) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container{
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3em;
        margin: 3%;
        /***************************/
        /* Change Here             */
        /***************************/
        border-left: 5px solid #FFF;
        border-right: 5px solid #FFF;
        /**** END CHANGE ************/
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
    }
    .logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .logo2{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
        <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2">LOGO 2</div>
    </div>
```

Alternatively you could use `border-style: solid none`

```css
body {
  background: url(https://www.gohawaii.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_gallery_bg_xl/public/hero-unit-images/11500_mauibeaches.jpg?itok=I2TvGlCa) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 94%;
  padding: 3em;
  margin: 3%;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  /** ONE LINE CHANGE BELOW **/
  border-style: solid none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
      augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
      augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="logo2">LOGO 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly

```
.container{
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```